Bootstrap's modal doesn't work on areas with external jQuery link ASP.NET Core 8
I'm curious why bootstrap's modal works on an ASP.NET Core areas in case of internal jQuery scripts but doesn't work with external link while works outside ASP.NET Core areas with both internal scripts and external link.
I expect a modal works properly with external link which referenced at layout that exists outside areas.
thanks in advance for your attention and answer.
Let me add screenshots.








Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In this case just clear cached data of browser.

According to your description, I suggest you could check below things, firstly make sure you have use the right _ViewStart with the right path for the layout.
LIke below:
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Secondly, I suggest you could re-check your layout's jquery , bootstarp or else  script and css's version to make sure it match your internal scripts link.
Thirdly, you should use the @scrtion to make sure the scripts is running well.
Like below:
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showCreate(1)">
    Create Record
</button>
    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="createModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="createModalLabel">Create Seizure</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                   
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-content">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @section Scripts {



        <script type="text/javascript">

            function showCreate(rqKey) {
                document.getElementById('modal-body-content').innerHTML = "test descriptin here";
                $('#createModal').modal('show');

            }
        </script>
    }

Result:

